# Reading Output of Logcat From Java Code in Android

Tags: android, logcat

I need to write a code in which I need to read the media framework logs in android java code.

I've a rooted device and have modified the `AwesomePlayer.cpp`.

In the java code I do

```
process =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(" logcat -f /sdcard/data/log.txt");
```

and then after a  few statements I do,

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/sdcard/data/log.txt")));
```

and then use br, to read the log files.

Here I just get the logs specific to Runtime or Dalvik VM, no logs from AwesomePlayer are displayed.

If I do logcat `-f /sdcard/data/log.txt` from device control, I get all the desired logs.

I tried giving `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />` in manifest file to no avail.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: The Android security model normally prohibits 3rd party apps from accessing logs other than their own.  You must use your `su` root shim to launch logcat.  It is also possible that manually installing the app on the system partition might enable the read logs permission request, but unsure on that.